# Magento 2 command line install (too many arguments)

Tags: magento2, installation, install-script, command-line

so I am trying to make a bash script in Magento, and I am learning from the bottom up.
So I have the basic arguments ready to be used in the script I am making, but when I execute

`sudo php magento setup:install --admin-user="user"`

or a variation with `[--admin-user="user"]`

I get

`[RuntimeException]
Too many arguments.`

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I would like to put that line in my script, so I can install Magento with user defined variables

I am using Magento 2.0.2 with Sample Data on Ubuntu 15.02

Comment: I recently wrote a simple bash script for setting up Magento 2 that creates an instance from a GitHub repo, sets up an Nginx config and installs the software based on user input. You may be interested in it https://github.com/affinitycloud/magesetup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have forgot about the `--` in front of the command. (So it seems in your screenshot).

Comment: Stupid me, the command works now! thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and the correct installation command is:

```
php bin/magento setup:install 
--base-url="http://example.co.uk/" 
--db-host="localhost" 
--db-name="databasename" 
--db-user="databaseuser" 
--db-password="databasepass" 
--admin-firstname="Yourname" 
--admin-lastname="Yourname" 
--admin-email="hello@example.co.uk" 
--admin-user="admin" 
--admin-password="setpasswordhere" 
--language="en_GB" 
--currency="GBP" 
--timezone="Europe/London" 
--use-rewrites="1" 
--backend-frontname="admin"
```

[Install Magento 2 using CLI](https://devblg.co.uk/how-to-install-magento-2/)

As mentioned, in your case command line options for the Magento 2 CLI installer require **--** before the option name (e.g **--base-url="example.com"**)

Comment: in wamp its working fine for `magento2.3` and `php7.2.4`. make sure its in single line.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the double brackets and run the following command.

```
bin/magento setup:install --backend-frontname="adminlogin" \
--key="biY8vdWx4w8KV5Q59380Fejy36l6ssUb" \
--db-host="localhost" \
--db-name="magentodb" \
--db-user="root" \
--db-password="secretpassword" \
--language="en_US" \
--currency="GBP" \
--timezone="Europe/London" \
--use-rewrites=1 \
--use-secure=0 \
--base-url="http://www.newmagento.com" \
--base-url-secure="https://www.newmagento.com" \
--admin-user=adminuser \
--admin-password=admin123@ \
--admin-email=admin@newmagento.com \
--admin-firstname=admin \
--admin-lastname=user \
--cleanup-database
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new file name it install.sh , use a text editor to paste that command , save it.
chmod +x install.sh and do ./install.sh

Answer (score 0):

You can use proper command line

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/sport/" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="sports" --db-user="root" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="admin@admin.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin"
```