# Magento 2: Too many arguments for install using the command line

Tags: magento2, installation, command-line

I'm trying to install Magento 2 on Debian-system from the command line.

And by running:

```
php magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/magento2" 
--db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento2_db" --db-user="magento2_user" 
--db-password="*password" --admin-user="admin" 
--admin-password="*password" admin-firstname="admin" 
--admin-lastname="user" --use-sample-data --cleanup-database
```

I'm getting only:

```
[RuntimeException]
Too many arguments.
```

viewed that question [Magento 2 command line install (too many arguments)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102366/magento-2-command-line-install-too-many-arguments) too, but cant help me further...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  `--` before `admin-firstname` to resolve the issue.

like

```
php magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/magento2" 
--db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento2_db" --db-user="magento2_user" 
--db-password="*password" --admin-user="admin" 
--admin-password="*password" --admin-firstname="admin" 
--admin-lastname="user" --use-sample-data --cleanup-database
```

Comment: thanks, can´t tell why didnt seen it >.<
getting next errors now... however that one issue has gone! thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a space between the = sign that caused this error IE: --admin-user = "admin"